# How to get the Gradle build directory in a Java annotation processor

Tags: gradle, annotation-processing

I am writing a custom annotation processor in Java which needs to create a file.

It seems to me the best location for that file would be in a new folder inside the Gradle's `$buildDir`.

For a project without modules, the environment property "user.dir" seems to hold a value I could use.

However, that environment property changes if the project has modules and the `gradlew build` command is executed either from inside or outside a module.

What is the best approach to actually get in Java the Gradle build directory of the module in which the annotation processor is declared ?

P.S.

I do not want to create that file in the "build/generated" folder (this is what `processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile(..)` does).

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way around : choose a location and set it up in your `build.gradle`

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = file("your/custom/path")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain why I should do it this way?

Comment: your code can't depend on your build system. If tomorrow it's not built anymore with Gradle, it won't work.

Comment: ok, you're right. But even if I switched to Maven, I'd still like to know the location of the folder the project is built in, eg. "target" in case of Maven. I thought that's what it was for... So, yes, I can provide the subfolder in which I'd like my files to end up, as long as it will be a subfolder within the folder all other build files are.